# Is it possible to search and replace formatting in a LibreOffice Writer document with named styles?

Tags: find-and-replace, styles, libreoffice-writer, text-formatting

Say I have a document in Writer that somebody who is ignorant of styles has created by manually setting a certain font to various areas.

Now I want to improve the document by upgrading the manual formatting to styles.

Using the font example, is there a way to find all portions that have said font manually set and replace that formatting with a style of a given name?

If not via the Search and Replace dialog, any other method of changing hand-made formatting into actual styles?

Answer (score 9):

In the `Edit -> Find & Replace` dialog, expand `More Options` and click the Format button.  In the font tab, specify the font to find and press OK.  Also click on the Attributes button and check the Font box.

Before closing the dialog, press the `Find All` button.  This will select all text where the font was set manually.

Now open the Styles and Formatting pane by going to `Styles -> Styles and Formatting`, or press F11.  Then double-click on a style.  It will change all selected text to that style.

For a more powerful approach, try one of these add-ons:

- [Alt-Search](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/alternative-dialog-find-replace-writer-altsearch) (I didn't test converting to styles, but it looks like it would work)
- [LingTools](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/lingtools) using Data Conversion.  The SIL Converters application is not needed for this task.